# Is it possible to enable/disable checkbox in vue-good-table?

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

Im passing the property to vue-good-table `:select-options="{enabled: true}"` to show checkbox for each row. I want to conditionally override this for certain rows. For example, if the column 'isAuthorized' has the value `false`, the checkbox should not be shown for that row. How to achieve this? Should I implement custom checkbox under  `<template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">`? Is there a built-in feature available in vue-good table?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same issue and found a way:

You can set `vgtDisabled:true` on the rows that should not be selectable.
Similarly, you can set `vgtSelected:true` for the rows that should be already checked by default.

I found by looking into source of the component here:
https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/blob/d2d0a781ed823c40a3bf14efceac82626e48d67c/src/components/Table.vue#L238

Comment: sadly the "select all" checkbox in the table header ignores this: https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/848